# Is there an equivalent model to the Hidden Markov Model for continuous hidden variables?

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model, kalman-filter

I understand that Hidden Markov Models are used to learn about hidden variables $z_i$ with the help of observable variables $\xi_i$. On Wikipedia, I read that while the $\xi_i$'s can be continuous (say Gaussian), the $z_i$'s are **discrete**. Is this necessary, and why? Are there ways in which I could extend this to continuous domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Kalman filter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) is what you're looking for.

According to Wikipedia:

> The Kalman filter may be regarded as analogous to the hidden Markov model, with the key difference that the hidden state variables take values in a continuous space (as opposed to a discrete state space as in the hidden Markov model).